# Facebook SDK on Android: WebDialog closing after giving authorization

Tags: java, android, facebook, dialog

I'm creating an app for Android and I've integrated the Facebook SDK to present the users a Feed Dialog with the following code:

```
public void showDialog()
{
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("description", "description about link");
    parameters.putString("link", "http://google.nl");
    parameters.putString("name","Name of link");
    parameters.putString("caption","describe your caption text");
    parameters.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    WebDialog feedDialog = new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this, Session.getActiveSession(), parameters).build();

    feedDialog.show();
}
```

I call this method after I've created the session:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() 
    {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
        {
            if(session.isOpened()) showDialog();
        }
    };
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);
}
```

The WebDialog comes up and I can login. Then It says that I've already authorized this app but after that, the dialog closes without a warning or something. I don't know why this is the case: all the parameters seems to be ok. Can anyone help me with this and explain why the dialog disappears?

Comment: i have similar problem did u find solution for this?